# VS2015 + TypeScript + Cordova + Angular2 + SystemJS

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, systemjs

I'm having problem with `systemJS` loading external modules.  I created a small sample project for VS2015.  You can download the code here https://github.com/dbiele/TypeScript-Cordova-SystemJS

When I build the project and view in Ripple or BrowserSync I get the following error: `xhr_proxy`.  It looks like `System` is looking for the external file `animate.js` on registry.jspm.io when it should be finding it on the `localhost`.

Any thoughts? The code in GitHub is really basic. Note: I don't think this is a Cordova issue because I'm running in a browser and ripple.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.  TypeScript does not use the `.js` extension when importing/exporting external modules.  For example:

#### TypeScript

```
import * as Animate from './animate';
```

ES6

```
import * as Animate from './animate.js';
```

The solution is to add `defaultJSExtensions: true` into system.config.

Example:

```
System.config({
    baseURL: './scripts/',
    paths: { 'App': 'app.js' },
    defaultJSExtensions: true
});
```

I updated the VS2015 project code here and it works well.

https://github.com/dbiele/TypeScript-Cordova-SystemJS

@DatenMetzgerX had the same problem.  Posted info:
https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/490