# Creating typescript's objects from another *.ts file

Tags: class, object, typescript

Basicly what I want to do is to have each class in seperate .ts file

test.ts

```
export class TestClass{
  constructor(){}
  public color: string = 'red';
}
```

test2.ts

```
/// <reference path="test.ts"/>

var classt = new TestClass();
alert(classt.color);
```

When I try to compile it, it gives me error: "test2.ts(8,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'TestClass'.". Can it be done that way?

Comment: You should use file modules https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/// <reference path="test.ts"/>` is not the suggested way to pull in additional files.

The suggested way is to import the file:

```
import { TestClass } from './test.ts';
// use TestClass
```

That being said, to fix what you have, you can still use triple slash references but you will need it to be a local path...

```
/// <reference path="./test.ts"/>
// note the ./ in the reference above
```

Comment: When I change this to ./filename, it gives me error, that this file doesn't exist.

Comment: ./test.ts would refer to that file if they were in the same directory... if it is not, then you can do ./foo/bar/test.ts if that's the directory structure (they're relative)

Comment: I don't know why this isn't working, but suggestions in the answer are ok, so accepted and voted up

Comment: @berrigan I was having difficult figuring out external modules too.  Here's a sample project I created for `VS2015 Community` [https://github.com/dbiele/TypeScript-Cordova-SystemJS](https://github.com/dbiele/TypeScript-Cordova-SystemJS)  More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893436/vs2015-typescript-cordova-angular2-systemjs